# laptop running relatively hot playing media

Tags: laptop, music, multimedia, music-player

I have an Acer 5740dg (core i5) and Ubuntu 11.10. After tweaking a little with the grub workaround and jupiter I don't have any heating problems anymore. Its even cooler than Windows. 
Except I'm playing media. Even under Audacious it heats 10° C up. Is this normal for such simple Audio Player (I have this with every player)?
I already switched from Pulse to ALSA, but doesn't help. With htop I see that the CPU isn't asked very much. 
What could be the reason?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Audacious is not reach in features but is not light. People see it as lightweight because they compare it with  heavy bloatware like Amarok and Rhythbox. But I find that Aqualung or Quod Libet are lighter than Audacious.(Try Qmmp if you want an even smaller one or some of the basic ones like Open Cubic to see if  your problem remains.)

What I really recommend is DeaDBeef. How to install see [here](http://cipricuslinux.blogspot.com/2012/02/install-from-ppa-deadbeef-player.html) in my blog. It looks [like that](http://cipricuslinux.blogspot.com/p/my-xubuntu-screenshots.html).

Your expression "even cooler than Windows" struck me : UBUNTU is meant to be THAT too. If it is not, or not always, it might be that your computer (like mine) is not ready for the new Gnome/Unity desktop environment. DO you use that? I find it bloated. See [this article](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/11/09/xcfe_for_gnome_refugees/).